# php get total worked hours from start time to end time with multiple entries for day

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

Im trying to build a clock in clock out system. When trying to get a report of hours worked by a user for a given day i need to total the number of hours worked. I have a startTime (timestamp) and endTime (timestamp) but i can have multiple entries for a user on any given day whre they clock in go to break clock out then clcok in after and out for lunch and so on.

```
 array
  (
        [theUser] => Bob Johnson
        [timeId] => 9
        [user_id] => 1
        [weekNo] => 34
        [clockYear] => 2016
        [entryDate] => 2016-08-21
        [startTime] => 2016-08-21 21:57:01
        [endTime] => 2016-08-21 22:45:15
        [updated_at] => 2016-08-21 22:45:15
        [totTime] => 00:48:14
    ) 

    [9] => Array
    (
        [theUser] => Bob Johnson
        [timeId] => 16
        [user_id] => 1
        [weekNo] => 34
        [clockYear] => 2016
        [entryDate] => 2016-08-24
        [startTime] => 2016-08-24 01:00:00
        [endTime] => 2016-08-24 05:15:00
        [updated_at] => 
        [totTime] => 04:15:00
    )
    (
        [theUser] => Bob Johson
        [timeId] => 15
        [user_id] => 1
        [weekNo] => 34
        [clockYear] => 2016
        [entryDate] => 2016-08-24
        [startTime] => 2016-08-24 01:00:00
        [endTime] => 2016-08-24 05:15:00
        [updated_at] => 
        [totTime] => 04:15:00
    )

    (
        [theUser] => Bob Johnson
        [timeId] => 18
        [user_id] => 1
        [weekNo] => 34
        [clockYear] => 2016
        [entryDate] => 2016-08-24
        [startTime] => 2016-08-24 09:59:00
        [endTime] => 2016-08-24 10:45:00
        [updated_at] => 2016-08-24 10:19:31
        [totTime] => 00:46:00
    )
```

I need to make new array with the total hours worked summed up I would like to achieve something like this

```
         (
                [theUser] = Bob Johnson
                [weekNo] = 34
                [Year] = 2016
                [entryDate] = 2016-08-24
                [totalHoursWorked] = 09:16:00
                [overTime] = 01:16:00
            )
```

Can anyone help with this please if tried taking

```
          $startTime = strtotime($val['startTime']);
          $endTime = strtotime($val['endTime']);
          $tot += $endTime - $startTime;

          echo date('H:i:s', $tot)
```

in a foreach loop but i always get wrong values

Comment: I guess you can do this by parsing the array, but in this instance, I think I'd be tempted to do it in the query itself.

Comment: What is the output of the `strtotime($val['startTime']);` code? It's a unix timestamp, not a formatted date...

Comment: Yes it's a time stamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your last line: `echo date('H:i:s', $tot)`

You should use [`gmdate`](https://www.php.net/gmdate) instead:

```
echo gmdate('H:i:s', $tot);
```

Or format it with a simple math code:

```
$hours = floor($init / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $init % 60;

echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

Answer (score 0):

using a library such as [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) will be more convenient for your calculation and formating